# ldapadd fails with error: no attributes provided

Tags: configuration, ldap

I want to fill my example ldap server with the entry user and 2 users with the attributes: uid, sn, cn, employeeType and userPassword like the following:

```
dn: dc=example, dc=com
objectclass: organization
objectclass: top
o: example

dn: ou=user, dc=example, dc=com
objectclass: ou
ou: user

dn: uid=john, ou=user, dc=example, dc=com
objectclass: person
uid: john
sn: Doe
cn: John Doe
employeeType: admin
userPassword: 123456

dn: uid=peter, ou=user, dc=example, dc=com
objectclass: person
uid: peter
sn: Doe
cn: Peter Doe
employeeType: employer
userPassword: 654321
```

with the command `ldapadd -x -D 'cn=root,dc=example,dc=com' -W` I get the error

```
adding new entry "ou=user, dc=example, dc=com   objectclass: ou   ou: user"
ldap_add: Protocol error (2)
        additional info: no attributes provided
```

I think the problem is my **slapd.conf** file:

```
#
# See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
# This file should NOT be world readable.
#
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/samba.schema

# Define global ACLs to disable default read access.

# Do not enable referrals until AFTER you have a working directory
# service AND an understanding of referrals.
#referral   ldap://root.openldap.org

pidfile     /run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /run/openldap/slapd.args

# Load dynamic backend modules:
# modulepath    /usr/lib/openldap
# moduleload    back_mdb.la
# moduleload    back_ldap.la

# Sample security restrictions
#   Require integrity protection (prevent hijacking)
#   Require 112-bit (3DES or better) encryption for updates
#   Require 63-bit encryption for simple bind
# security ssf=1 update_ssf=112 simple_bind=64

# Sample access control policy:
#   Root DSE: allow anyone to read it
#   Subschema (sub)entry DSE: allow anyone to read it
#   Other DSEs:
#       Allow self write access
#       Allow authenticated users read access
#       Allow anonymous users to authenticate
#   Directives needed to implement policy:
# access to dn.base="" by * read
# access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
 access to *
    by self write
    by dn.exact="cn=root,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by users read
    by anonymous auth
#
# if no access controls are present, the default policy
# allows anyone and everyone to read anything but restricts
# updates to rootdn.  (e.g., "access to * by * read")
#
# rootdn can always read and write EVERYTHING!

#######################################################################
# MDB database definitions
#######################################################################

database    mdb
maxsize     1073741824
suffix     "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn     "cn=root,dc=example,dc=com"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoid.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND 
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory   /var/lib/openldap/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass eq
index   uid             pres,eq
index   mail            pres,sub,eq
index   cn              pres,sub,eq
index   sn              pres,sub,eq
index employeeType  pres,sub,eq
index   dc              eq
rootpw    {SSHA}DM9oXLQZWLwdHuQP6EwlbYJFij+qJ27A
```

What do I have to change in my slapd.conf file to be able to add the hierarchy and entries I need?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with the command `ldapadd -x -D 'cn=root,dc=example,dc=com' -W -f example.ldif`.
The content of the example.ldif was:

```
dn: ou=user, dc=example, dc=com
objectclass: ou
ou: user

dn: uid=john, ou=user, dc=example, dc=com
objectclass: person
uid: john
sn: Doe
cn: John Doe
employeeType: admin
userPassword: 123456

dn: uid=peter, ou=user, dc=example, dc=com
objectclass: person
uid: peter
sn: Doe
cn: Peter Doe
employeeType: employer
userPassword: 654321
```